# docker : error In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect

Tags: docker

error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.

I'll make a new docker container for deploy java server image, not a have been used image.
and I did checked the windows features like a hyper-v, linux
than typed the command to the cmd or powershell
cd "C:Program Files\docker\docker" ./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon,
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart
wsl --set-default-version 2
wsl --install -d Ubuntu-20.04

but still happen problem is error during connect
what's going on? somebody help me? for solve the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.